# Rasa: How to provide hyperparameters to custom components?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am creating a custom component to add it in the Rasa NLU pipeline. For this I felt a need to add parameters/hyperparameters via the pipeline configuration just like we have for inbuilt pipelines like "WhitespaceTokenizer" as shown below.

```
pipeline:
- name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
  intent_split_symbol: "_"
```

The above pipeline has "intent_split_symbol" as the hyperparameter for "WhitespaceTokenizer". Similarly, I want to provide hyperparameter for my pipeline.

For eg.

```
pipeline:
- name: "MyCustomComponent"
  model: "en_user_convo"
```

How can I provide "model" hyperparameter in my "MyCustomComponent" custom component?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the config for your component in the same way as for the pre-defined components, e.g.

```
- name: "MyCustomComponent"
  param1: "test"
  param2: "second param"
```

The constructor of your component should accept a dictionary as parameter:

```py
from rasa.nlu.components import Component

class MyCustomComponent(Component):

def __init__(self, component_config: Optional[Dict[Text, Any]] = None) -> None:
   if component_config is not None:
       param1 = component_config.get("param1")
       # ...
       super().__init__(component_config)

# Rest of the component implementation
# ...
```

Does that make sense?